# Excel Copy/Paste Sheet and Rename Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

When you have a sheet and copy/paste it to a new sheet, I notice that all the tables are conveniently re-named to something unique so that the new sheet has independent table values from the first. For example, my table 'monthlyIncome' in sheet 1 will be renamed to something like 'monthlyIncome6' if I copy/paste the whole sheet to a new sheet in the workbook.

However, cell names are not renamed in this way. When you copy/paste the sheet, all cell names are dropped and revert back to their grid name (A1, J4 etc). The new sheet instead references the initial cell name, which is on the other sheet. So in this way the new sheet is not totally independent from the first one.

I have a somewhat complex sheet and do not want to go through and find all my cell name references and make them something unique for the second sheet. Is there a solution to do this for me? Like how it renames the table names?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clicking the top left of the sheet to select all cells and copy/past them, I needed to right click on the sheet and select 'move/copy'. When copied through that method, the cells keep their name, and excel always resolved scope by the most local variable first, so the cell names are not unique, but by default use the local cell name before the global workbook cell name.